# Unable to create JSON files from data, the document may not be well-formed json :Boomi

Tags: json, boomi

Recently i started doing a POC in Dell Boomi integration toll, and as part of the we are trying to load a json to insert to respective sql server table .

I am facing issue in mapping json to table data .

Here is the error i am facing .

```
The test run for a205061-research-process you are attempting completed with the following errors: Embedded message: [Input ProfileLocation: Root; DocumentLocation: /Root]: Unable to create JSON files from data, the document may not be well-formed json
```

My JSON looks like this .

```
{
  "t_Doc_DocGroup": [
    {
      "f_Doc_ID": "80510910",
      "f_DocGroup_Company_ID": "10333",
      "f_DocGroup_ID": "1",
      "f_ArriveDate": "9/2/2022 10:26:29 AM"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have created a json Profile and Imported this json to profile which looks like this .

[image]

when i try to map it to the table column and run then i get error

Can some one help me on how to resolve the issue .